# Sphinx searchd: failed to lock .spl file, no such file or directory

Tags: php, permissions, full-text-search, sphinx

I use sphinx for indexing on my development environment, and it is working fine. But when i take it to the server. I can index and I have the indexes with search working on them, but everytime I run the command: searchd --config configfile , it gives me an error:

```
Failed to lock .spl file, no such file or directory. not indexing

Fatal: no valid indexes to serve.
```

I gave permissions to write to that directory, so I am pretty sure it is not a permission issue. What could it be? Help please, it's been two weeks of trying to solve it with no success. I am really frustrated. Thanks

Comment: You need to give us more detaled information to help you. But this is not a programming question, you'd better to ask it at serverfault. By the way tje question is not related to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The files that is indexed by Indexer are located at /usr/local/sphinx/var/data.

Firstly, run indexer to create indexes files.if you already made check these out below:

Be sure that the indexed source file (.spl, .spd, .sph, .spk ... etc.) which is used by searchd in while searching, is located there (/usr/local/sphinx/var/data)

Look at your config file's  indexer configuration part (related ones)
there is a line ( path = /usr/local/sphinx2/var/data/srcDeltaUpdate ) or must be.